# Frontier steps for greedy best first search

Tags: artificial-intelligence, greedy-algorithms, search

I've been asked to list the frontier steps for greedy best-first search for the graph in the picture below.

I've attempted to recreate the algorithm in Golang, as shown below:

```golang
// Do takes a source (starting point), a target (endpoint)
func (g *GreedySearch[T]) Do(source, target *node.NodeWithCost[T]) []T {
    path := make([]T, 0)

    // Create a Set, this will house the 'visited' nodes, or 'closed' nodes.
    // Closed nodes are the nodes that have been visited and selected as the chosen path... I think?
    g.Visited = graph.Set[T]{Values: make(map[T]bool)}

    // Creates a priority queue, the order is decided by the 'cost' value. For instance,
    // the distance between two nodes. The shortest node is selected
    g.Queue = queues.NewPriorityQueue(g.Neighbours[*source])

    // We add the source node as the first node in the queue
    g.Queue.Add(source)

    // We then also set the source node as 'visited' in the set
    g.Visited.Values[source.Name] = true

    // Next, we loop over the queue, whilst there are values
    // still in the queue
    for {
        if len(g.Queue.Nodes) > 0 {
            popped := g.Queue.Pop()

            path = append(path, popped.Name)

            // If we reach the target, then WE ARE DONE 
            if popped == target {
                return path
            }

            frontier := g.Neighbours[*popped]

            var frontiers []T

            // We expand the neighbours of the next selected node
            // from the queue. We check that that node hasn't already
            // been visited. We then add it to the visited nodes,
            // and add the neighbours of that node to the queue.
            // This is similar to breadth first search, except that
            // the 'cost' value is considered as part of the queue.
            for _, v := range frontier {
                frontiers = append(frontiers, v.Name)
                if g.Visited.Values[v.Name] == false {
                    g.Visited.Values[v.Name] = true
                    g.Queue.Add(v)
                }
            }

            g.Steps = append(g.Steps, frontiers)
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following test:

```golang
func TestGreedyFirstSearch(t *testing.T) {
    is := is.New(t)

    g := graph.NewWithCost[string]()

    a5 := node.NewNodeWithCost("a", 5)
    b6 := node.NewNodeWithCost("b", 6)
    c8 := node.NewNodeWithCost("c", 8)
    d4 := node.NewNodeWithCost("d", 4)
    e4 := node.NewNodeWithCost("e", 4)
    f5 := node.NewNodeWithCost("f", 5)
    g2 := node.NewNodeWithCost("g", 2)
    h0 := node.NewNodeWithCost("h", 0)

    g = g.
        AddNode(a5).AddNode(b6).AddNode(c8).AddNode(d4).
        AddNode(e4).AddNode(f5).AddNode(g2).AddNode(h0).
        AddNeighbour(a5, b6).AddNeighbour(a5, c8).AddNeighbour(b6, d4).AddNeighbour(c8, f5).
        AddNeighbour(d4, e4).AddNeighbour(e4, f5).AddNeighbour(e4, g2).AddNeighbour(f5, g2).
        AddNeighbour(g2, h0)

    searcher := GreedySearch[string]{g}
    path := searcher.Do(a5, h0)

    is.Equal(path, []string{"a", "b", "d", "e", "g", "h"})
    is.Equal(searcher.ListSteps(), [][]string{
        {"b", "c"},
        {"a", "d"},
        {"b", "e"},
        {"d", "f", "g"},
        {"e", "f", "h"},
    })
    log.Println(searcher.ListSteps())
    log.Println(path)
}
```

The tests pass, but I just wanted to double-check I had the correct solution and that the frontier steps looked correct, as I'm having a difficult time trying to picture each step

[image: graph data structure]

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). I'd suggest asking about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Very good point, apologies @D.W.